# Using string enumeration as key of map SCSS

Tags: sass

I have created some amount of breakpoints to hide `nth-child` on certain screen width and I'm curious to make it more compact using loop and map. And it's OK with single media query condition, but I'm stuck with creating map, where key can be multiple media query condition, for example `@include media('<1000px', '>500px');`. As I get maps right, key can be any string, so theoretically it's possible to additionally quote this conditions enumeration and unquote it in the loop, but it's not working. Could someone help me with it?

```
@import "include-media";

$map: (
    "'>500px', '<1000px'": '9',
    "'<400px'": '7'
);

@each $condition, $child in $map {
    @include media(unquote($condition)) {
        :nth-child(n+#{$child}) {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I was trying to double quote an enumeration of strings to unquote it and pass to `media` function, but later I realize that everything's OK with my code, posted in answer, just I can't pass a few arguments as an unquoted string with string enumeration, it's impossible. So I was searching for a another way to store a patch of conditions and I remembered about SCSS lists. And this was the answer!

I didn't know that SCSS list can be keys in maps, but this is. So I just put all the conditions I need to the key and child number as a value, then iterate through the map and pass a conditions list to `media` function via deconstructing (I didn't find a lot of info about this operator and don't know how does it call :) ). So it ends like this:

```
$map: (
    ('>500px', '<1000px'): 9,
    ('<400px'): 7
);

@each $conditions, $child in $map {
    @include media($conditions...) {
        :nth-child(n + #{$child}) {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

which is converting to

```
@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 999px) {
  :nth-child(n+9) {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 399px) {
  :nth-child(n+7) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```